# How can we change the marker size after zooming in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm using jqPlot to render a graph with zooming enabled.

See example:
http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/yGLmT/

In the example above, I have a chart with a markerSize of 5 and I have a working zoom-event detection.

I need the plot to change its markerSize, when zoomed in. and reset it to its default, when zoomed out.

I was thinkingt of a solution, without replotting the graph. Since replotting looses the actual zoom level.

For example:

```
plot1.replot(options)
```

would change the markerSize, but looses the zoom level again.

Comment: Update your fiddle, it doesn't shows graph. Why you need to update cursor size

Comment: Does it show now? I see the graph...
I don't need to update the cursor size. I would like to increase the marker size (I mean the size of the points on the graph).

Comment: I think you can use plot1.series[0].markerSize

Comment: @AnthonyLeGovic Doesn't work ):

Answer (score 0):

Try updating options value using,

```
options.seriesDefaults['size'] = 25;
```

Then `reploat/redraw` the graph. But re plotting will surely resize the graph.

Comment: That's the issue. Replotting will resize the graph to its default setting and I will loose the cropped interval.

Comment: Then jqplot is open source, update the file as per your requirement and share it with us.

Comment: I would, if I could :D